# create multiple form pages of same data in one apex page

Tags: apex, pdf, repeat, renderas

I have below VF Page working fine. But I need to repeat this form multiple times in the PDF Page based on User input integer variable value. Please let me know the way it can be made possible?

**Apex Page**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" doctype="html-4.01-strict" controller="cntl_FormTemplatePrinter" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" cache="false" >



<apex:repeat value="{!formTransactions}" var="sof">
    <apex:dynamicComponent id="dcx" componentValue="{!ValidTemplate}" />

</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list If user enter 5 then iterate that list 5 times and add dummy string

```
Integer intUserInput = 5;
List<Integer> lstInteger = new List<Integer>();

for(Integer i = 1; i< intUserInput; i++)
{
 lstInteger.add(i);
}
```

In VF page

Add one more repeat

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstInteger}" var="int">
   <!--Add your code here (Apex repeat and dynamic component)
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I was about to Thank you friend! It worked for me !!

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Most welcome.

Comment: Can you please help me in new question too?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Sure let me check